Does Helldivers 2 still require a PSN account link on PC (Steam)?
According to multiple sources (for example, this PCMag article), Helldivers 2 no longer requires a PSN account to play the game on PC.
However, on the Steam page, it says,

Requires 3rd-Party account: Playstation Network (Supports Linking to Steam Account)

So do you need a PSN account or not?

A PSN account is not required to play Helldivers 2 on Steam.
For context, Sony had intended from the start to require PSN account linking to play the game on Steam. However, due to some reason (I heard technical difficulties but I am unsure), PSN linking to Steam was optional at release.
In May, they announced that the PSN requirement was coming to Steam, a huge backlash happened, and Sony backed out. However, they still delisted the game on Steam for countries and regions where PSN isn't officially supported.
To this day, PSN linking is still optional. The message you mentioned has been present since the game's release (when PSN was already optional) and has just never been changed.

Relevant link from the HellDivers Devs: https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/553850/view/4196868529806518741
